# is there a better way to swap players symbols?

Tags: java, button, javafx

I'm making XO game by JavaFX, so I need a way to swap between "X"s and "O"s with each new turn, could you please check what I've come up with and tell if there a better way to swap them

```
    boolean turnSwaper=true;
public void play(ActionEvent e){
    String player="";
    if(turnSwaper){
        player="X";
        turnSwaper=false;
    }else {
        player="O";
        turnSwaper=true;
    }
    Button pressed=(Button)e.getSource();
    pressed.setText(player);
    pressed.setDisable(true);
}
```

Comment: As for inverting `turnSwaper`: `turnSwapper = !turnSwapper;` would cover both cases. I doubt that the `play` method is a good place to hardcode the player symbols. Maybe a type containing data/functionality for a player is a good idea, but I don't know about the rest of the code, so I don't know if this is necessary/bebeficial...

Comment: your can do `player = turnSwaper ? "X" : "O" ` and `turnSwaper = ! turnSwaper` or you can begin by `turnSwaper = false` and then : `player = (turnSwaper = ! turnSwaper ) ? "X" : "O" `